# Conditional Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a conditional looping, perhaps Do Until or some similar that will run through the range of cells (say A3:A13) and if there’s a blank cell within that range there would be a command that will automatically hide entire row where the blank cell sits.(if the blank cell is A5 this mean entire row 5 would be hidden) The command will run through until all the the blank cells are detected and automatically all the rows associated with blank cells are hidden until it reach the end of the range A13. Any suggestions kindly welcome.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and keep in mind that this is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. First we loop through the `range("A" & LRow)` it will map all the blank cells and hide all in one go.

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long
Dim HideRng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
     LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To LRow


            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).value)) = 0 Then
                If HideRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set HideRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set HideRng = Union(HideRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not HideRng Is Nothing Then HideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Set HideRng = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for help and sorry for late response. Just a quick question, how could I apply above code only to a certain range in column A. Say I would like to search for a range (“A5:A15”) not entire column A and then hide the row/rows that contains blank cell. Is it possible?? Any help would be welcomed.